# Unique characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
function unique_char(string) {
  return String.prototype.concat(...new Set(string));
}

console.log(unique_char("Hellooooooooooooo"));
```

Can anyone help me understand how .concat a new Set will return unique characters ?
I thought .concat will add , and why is there a spread operating ... before new Set?

Comment: The Set will be a collection of all unique characters in a string. By spreading the Set into the concat method you’re simply joining each element in the set up by spreading each element in the Set as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

**1)**

```
new Set(string)
```

As `strings` in JS are iterable so `Set` will take string as an input and gives you set of unique characters.

**2)**

```
String.prototype.concat(...new Set(string)
```

> The concat() method concatenates the string `arguments` to the calling string and returns a new string.. `One or more strings` to concatenate to str. - MDN

So `concat` will take character by character and `append` it into a single string

**Have a look at the output of the following function**

```js
function unique_char(string) {
  const set = new Set(string);
  console.log(...set);

  return String.prototype.concat(...set);
}

console.log(unique_char("Hellooooooooooooo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

So lets cut this command in the single pices:

1. `new Set(string)` => this will create a new Set from the string and leave every char only once
2. the `...` is used to "convert" the Set to an array (the set is iterable)
3. the `String.prototype.concat` is used to concat all characters from the array that was returned by the spread operator.

Comment: The spread operator does not convert the Set to an array.